# Extracting Element from html document for android app using Jsoup

Tags: javascript, android, html, jsoup

I am trying to extract the text from this id to use in an android app I am trying to build.

`<div id="114561_435450">CSE423 - DMH - UB30301<br></div>`

As I am using Jsoup Library I already tried using `getElementById("114561_435450")` and `div[id=114561_435450].text()`. I am pretty much frustrated right now. Please any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try `document.getElementById`? please elaborate / post more code...

Comment: Yes I tried. 
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(mLoginURL)
                        .data("j_username",username)
                        .data("j_password",password)
                        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                        .post()
                        ;
String content=doc.getElementById("114561_435450").text();

Comment: Can you post the line of code where you parse the source html into a JSoup document? It would help a lot if you could post the URL from which you are getting the html.

Comment: @luksch Not solved yet.
I am logging in this page "usis.bracu.ac.bd"
After logging in I will get this page "usis.bracu.ac.bd/academia/dashBoard/show".

I am trying HtmlUnit right now. With Jsoup I have logged in successfully but couldn't parse html element.

Comment: as suggested in my answer, you need to identify the AJAX call that is made by the site and call this yourself with JSoup, if possible. Don't forget to set all cookies correctly when you do this. Other than that, yes HTMLUnit might be able to do it. Or Use Selenium and PhantomJs

Answer (score 0):

Using purely Javascript, the following should work:

```
getElementById("114561_435450").innerHTML
```

If you can use jQuery, the following should also work:

```
$("#114561_435450").html()
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, Thank you very much. I tried document.getElementById("114561_435450").innerHTML in the chrome console and its worked perfectly. But whenever I tried in Android studio its saying 'can not  resolve innerHTML'. I have never worked with js. So can you give me any kind of advice how can I implement this command?

Comment: I am not familiar with Android Studio, but from what I understand you are using JSoup, and not actual Javascript.  If that is the case, try `.html()` instead of `.innerHTML`, as indicated by the [JSoup documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#html--).

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible reasons, why your code may not work

1. The id is changing with each request to the page. This is easy to check for, just load the url again in a browser and see if the id changed. do not forget to clear cache and cookies between tests.
   If the id changes indeed, you need to find out more about the structure of the document in order to find the correct div.
2. The content of the document may be filled in by AJAX and thus not directly accessible to you. If this is the case you can find out by looking at a) the url loaded via curl or print it out from the Jsoup document and b) the network traffic when the page loads (Developer tools in Chrome or Firefox). If this is the case you should find out the URL of the AJAX call and get this instead of the original url.

Another solution to your problem may be the use of Selenium Webdriver. With this you actually remote control a real browser which should be perfectly able to execute any JavaScript that populates the DOM.

Comment: Hei. Number two is the case here. I have the URL of the AJAX call.